# Have a Tab Act as a Drawer React Native

Tags: react-native

I have not been able to find any example of such a navigation but essentially I am attempting to have a regular tab navigator with 4 tabs. What I want is for the right-most tab to open a drawer instead of showing a tab screen. You should be able to push it or swipe to it and pull out the drawer. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is possible, just have to use **Actions.drawerOpen()** in action of tab. If not get what I say, then please post your code, so I can give more details on it.

Thanks